# NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'void android.media.MediaRecorder.setAudioSource : Android

Tags: android

**java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'void android.media.MediaRecorder.setAudioSource(int)' on a null object reference**

Here is my log cat

```
11-02 15:04:19.184  30896-30896/com.example.tazeen.classnkk E/AndroidRuntime﹕ FATAL EXCEPTION: main
    Process: com.example.tazeen.classnkk, PID: 30896
    java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'void android.media.MediaRecorder.setAudioSource(int)' on a null object reference
            at com.example.tazeen.classnkk.ItemDetail_Record$1.onClick(ItemDetail_Record.java:171)
            at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:4756)
            at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:19748)
            at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:739)
            at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
            at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:135)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5254)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:898)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:693)
```

Error at this line **myAudioRecorder.setAudioSource(MediaRecorder.AudioSource.MIC);**

here is my voice record button code

```
imageRecord = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.image_Record);
        imageRecord.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                clickCount += 1;
                Log.e("clickCount ", " click !!! " + clickCount);

                if (clickCount == 1) {

                    if (vesselId == null) {

                        SimpleDateFormat s = new SimpleDateFormat("ddMMyyyyhhmmss");
                        newAudioFile = 0 + "_" + s.format(new Date()) + ".mp3";
                        Log.e(" newAudioFile ", " = " + newAudioFile);
                        outputFile = baseDir + "/classnkk_audio/" + newAudioFile;
                        Log.e("outputFile ", " = " + outputFile);

                        myAudioRecorder.setAudioSource(MediaRecorder.AudioSource.MIC);
                        myAudioRecorder.setOutputFormat(MediaRecorder.OutputFormat.THREE_GPP);
                        myAudioRecorder.setAudioEncoder(MediaRecorder.OutputFormat.AMR_NB);
                        myAudioRecorder.setOutputFile(outputFile);

                        imageRecord.setImageResource(R.drawable.record);
                        try {
                            myAudioRecorder.prepare();
                            myAudioRecorder.start();
                            myChronometer.start();

                        } catch (IllegalStateException e) {
                            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                            e.printStackTrace();
                        } catch (IOException e) {
                            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                            e.printStackTrace();
                        }

                    } else if (vesselId != null) {
                        SimpleDateFormat s = new SimpleDateFormat("ddMMyyyyhhmmss");
                        newAudioFile = vesselId + "_" + s.format(new Date()) + ".mp3";
                        Log.e(" newAudioFile ", " = " + newAudioFile);
                        outputFile = baseDir + "/classnkk_audio/" + newAudioFile;
                        Log.e("outputFile ", " = " + outputFile);

                        myAudioRecorder.setAudioSource(MediaRecorder.AudioSource.MIC);
                        myAudioRecorder.setOutputFormat(MediaRecorder.OutputFormat.THREE_GPP);
                        myAudioRecorder.setAudioEncoder(MediaRecorder.OutputFormat.AMR_NB);
                        myAudioRecorder.setOutputFile(outputFile);
                        imageRecord.setImageResource(R.drawable.record);
                        try {
                            myAudioRecorder.prepare();
                            myAudioRecorder.start();
                            myChronometer.start();

                        } catch (IllegalStateException e) {
                            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                            e.printStackTrace();
                        } catch (IOException e) {
                            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                            e.printStackTrace();
                        }
                    }

                } else if (clickCount == 2) {
                    imageRecord.setImageResource(R.drawable.record_pause);
                    myAudioRecorder.stop();
                    myAudioRecorder.reset();
                    myAudioRecorder.release();
                    myAudioRecorder = null;
                    myChronometer.stop();
                    long elapsedMillis = SystemClock.elapsedRealtime() - myChronometer.getBase();
                    Log.e("elapsedMillis ", " of myChronometer !!! " + elapsedMillis);
                }

                if (clickCount == 2) {
                    imageRecord.setImageResource(R.drawable.record);
                    clickCount = 0;
                    myAudioRecorder = null;
                    myChronometer.setBase(SystemClock.elapsedRealtime());
                    Log.e("(clickCount == 3 ) ", " click !!! " + clickCount);
                }
            }
        });
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Where initializing `myAudioRecorder` object?

Comment: Why to ban my asking questions ?

Comment: not ban they have marked your question as duplicate due to similar type of issue is available on SO. let me know still you are not able to solve current issue.thanks

Comment: There is 2 option edit this post and ask a new question , click to ask the new question and show this text = Sorry, we are no longer accepting questions from this account. See the Help Center to learn more.

Comment: Where did you initialise `myAudioRecorder`? That is crucial information.